# How to define a callback function for use with WinAPI function (midiInOpen)

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use `MMSystem` to call [midiInOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-midiinopen) but I'm unsure on how to pass the  `dwCallback` ([midiInProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd798460(v=vs.85))).

I've taken a look at `Winapi.MMSystem.pas` and the `midiInOpen` function is declared as the following which gives no clues as what to pass for `dwInstance`:

```
{$EXTERNALSYM midiInOpen}
function midiInOpen(lphMidiIn: PHMIDIIN; uDeviceID: UINT;
  dwCallback, dwInstance: DWORD_PTR; dwFlags: DWORD): MMRESULT; stdcall;
```

Does the callback function in Delphi have to be declared in a certain way or can I pass the address of procedure that has the same definition as the midiInProc defined in the WinAPI manual?

Comment: See API documentation before using an API function. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-midiinopen). dwInstance is whatever you pass, you then have it back when the callback is called. I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: I would like to pass a pointer to a callback function to `dwInstance` so I can process the incoming MIDI in messages. I'm new to Delphi and unsure how to define a callback function.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yup. I've already linked to both of those pages in my question. How do I define the function in Delphi? Is the callback function just a regular procedure in Delphi or do callbacks have to be defined in a certain way?

Comment: Ok. Link in your question. The callback can have any name but the signature should be identical, with stdcall calling convention. It should be a standalone function - not a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`midiInOpen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-midiinopen) documentation:

> dwCallback
>
> Pointer to a callback function, a thread identifier, or a handle of a window called with information about incoming MIDI messages. **For more information on the callback function, see [MidiInProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/dd798460(v=vs.85))**.

If you use a callback function, it must match the signature of `MidiInProc`:

```c
void CALLBACK MidiInProc(
  HMIDIIN   hMidiIn,
  UINT      wMsg,
  DWORD_PTR dwInstance,
  DWORD_PTR dwParam1,
  DWORD_PTR dwParam2
 );
```

For example

```pascal
procedure MyMidiInCallback(hMidiIn: HMIDIIN; wMsg: UINT; dwInstance, dwParam1, dwParam2: DWORD_PTR); stdcall;
begin
  // do something...
end;

...

var
  uDeviceID: UINT;
  hMidiIn: HMIDIIN;
begin
  uDeviceID := ...;
  midiInOpen(@hMidiIn, uDeviceID, DWORD_PTR(@MyMidiInCallback), 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
  ...
  midiInClose(hMidiIn);
end;
```